# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gwt

Upgrading project from spring 2.5 to 3.2 I have replaced the old spring jars with new spring 3.1.1 jars. When I deployed and trying to hit the server. I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lan
g/Class;
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:260)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:83)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:63)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:54)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:43)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I want to use org.springframework, spring, 2.5.6.SEC03 because old project is using SimpleFormController and AbstractFormController, i dont want to touch existing code and i want it to support annotated controller too.

below is the dependency i am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- weblogic 10 plugins start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.3.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn</artifactId>
    <version>2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- weblogic 10 plugins end -->


<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2_beta1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mockejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Junit Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Mockito Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Powermock Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc-struts</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11-beta2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11-beta2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.14</version>
</dependency>


<!-- XStream -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Newly added Jar file from win TTP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4c</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your pom has dependency `3.2.13.RELEASE` and you want to use `org.springframework spring 2.5.6.SEC03` can you clearify?

Comment: This error will come when there are more than 1 version of Spring in the classpath. Please ensure that there is only ONE SPRING VERSION in your classpath.

Comment: In my application we are using SimpleFormController which is only supported in spring 2.5, i dont want to touch existing code, so i am using both versions. 
Is it possible to support both SimpleFormController and annotated controller in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting it here as I dont have reps to add it in a comment.
Please remove the older version of spring if you want to use a new version.

It is a very bad idea to have multiple versions of spring in one application.
You will spend hours and hours of wasting time for solving **magical errors** occurs with your application just because of two versions of spring jars.

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same issue and I used the Maven Dependency BOM. It works perfect. The *---Version---Number* is the Spring Framework version you are using in your project.
Visit this link for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... other dependency elements ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>---Version---Number.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```